# How to select servers that does not have a date record in a separate table between a date range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table1 holds server info including server names
Table2 holds dates patches have been installed
Table3 holds backup data

I want to select a list of servers that does not have a date in table2 between a certain date range. Here is the query I tried that looks to me like it should work, but does not.

```
select distinct table1.name, table2.patchsuccess, table2.patcheddate, table3.backupdate
from table2
full join table1
    on table1.id = table2.fk_table1
full join table3
    on table3.fk_table1 = table1.id
where table2.patchsuccess between '2014-07-01' and '2014-09-1' and table1.decommissioned = 0
order by table1.name
```

What is a good way to pull the information I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.*, T3.*
FROM Table1 AS T1
JOIN Table3 AS T3
  ON T3.FK_Table1 = T1.ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Table2 AS T2 WHERE T2.fk_table1= T1.ID
                       AND T2.patchsuccess BETWEEN '2014-07-01' and '2014-09-1' )
  AND T1.Decomissioned = 0
```

Comment: "not in" tend to be slow.  "not exists" or "in these except those" are less intuitive, but run faster.

Comment: true, wasn't thinking about perf at this point but point taken... will modify.

Comment: I tried the code and received the following error:   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exists'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'.

Comment: I am now receiving multiple: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 The multi-part identifier "t3.fk_t1" could not be bound. The same for t1.id, t3.fk_t1, t2.patchsuccess,t1.decommissioned. I changed all of the column names to their alias t1, t2, t3 in the query and then received this message "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2014-07-01' to data type bit."

Comment: dude, it's your SQL that is wrong...  patchsuccess is a DATE??? or a BIT???  why does your SQL have it in the date BETWEEN ??

Comment: Yep, wrong column name was the problem; however, I am receiving records with dates between the times provided not the opposite. I want to list servers names that do not have a record between the dates specified and thanks for the help you have provided so far. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That was the answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2):

I would go with this construct.  You can fill in the details:

```
select blah, blah, blah
from YourTables join 
(select the IDs you want
except 
select the IDs you don't want) temp on SomeTable.id = temp.id
where whatever
```

Comment: Could you put in a little more details? I do not understand how to use the code you entered.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a spoon feeding site.  What's the part you don't understand?  Using "except"?  Joining to subqueries?  Something else?